# Selects all <p> elements if <p> Tag Contains Start with "Read:" Using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a lot of `<p>` tags on thousands of pages.

There are **hundreds of** `<p>` tags like below.

```
<p>Read: <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Example</a></p>
```

Those start with **Read:**.

I want t to apply some CSS to `<p>` tag only if the paragraph starts with **Read:**. Is it possible?

Comment: CSS doesn't have any selectors that target content. One line of JS can do it.

Comment: If you control the DOM set a data-attribute for each p tag that is for read. Then you could use CSS like `p[data-read="true"] { //some style }` set the p tag like `<p data-read="true">Read: //something</p>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not posible with CSS alone, you would need Javascript to achieve this.

This example shows you...

#1. How to use Javascript to search your documents p tags and find strings where the 1st index of the string is set to the target string `Read:` using `indexOf()`.

#2. How to then set an attribute, `el.setAttribute()`, on that tag that identifies that element as a `Read:` element containing the string we want to affect in our CSS.

#3. How to use CSS + elements attribute to then style the target elements in the DOM as you want them styled.

- `const p = [...document.getElementsByTagName('p')]` -> create an
  array of elements we can then loop over using `tag.forEach()`
- `tag.textContent.indexOf("Read:") === 0`-> lets find elements that
  have target string at the very beginning of the `tag.textContent`.
- `tag.setAttribute("data-read", true)` -> set the tags `data-read`
  *attribute* to `true`
- `p[data-read="true"]` in CSS we style all elements that are p tags
  and have the attribute `<p data-read="true">`

Using this method we are able to use CSS to style the tags and JS to find them.

```js
const p = [...document.getElementsByTagName('p')]

p.forEach(tag=>tag.textContent.indexOf("Read:") === 0 ?  tag.setAttribute("data-read", true) : false)
```

```css
p[data-read="true"] {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgreen;
}

p[data-read="true"]:after {
  content: ' *';
}
p[data-read="true"]:before {
  content: '* ';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Read: some info</p>
  <p>Read: some info</p>
  <p>p tag content</p>
  <p>more ptag info</p>  
  <p>Perhaps the p content has a sentence that starts with the string and we do not want to get that one. Read: Speak: Listen:</p>
  <p>Read: At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Read: More</p>
    <p>Read: More</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet Read: More</p>
    <script>
      let list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].textContent.startsWith("Read:")) {
          list[i].style.color = "red";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if CSS have such selectors but you can still achieve your goal with JavaScript

```
    let list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       if (list[i].textContent.startsWith("Read:")) {
           list[i].style.color = "red";
       }
    }
```

Comment: there is ``startWith` to improve the question :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Sysix. I added the necessary changes to the code, and now it works fine,